# Обращение к value

Tags: javascript, input

Условно есть `<input class="class "value = "x">`
Как с помощью JavaScript обратиться к этому input, взять его значение и вывести куда-либо (например в другой `<input type="text">`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const my__input = document.querySelector('.my__input');
const conclusion = document.querySelector('.conclusion');
my__input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  conclusion.innerHTML = value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="my__input">
<div class="conclusion"></div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' да он здесь и не решает особо, главное скрипт что работает

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector(".destination").value = document.querySelector(".source").value;
```

```html
<input class="source" value="x">
<input class="destination">
```